# How to make an Optional Arguement that requires no value in Python(but only the command)

Tags: python, argparse

I have a program, that can run like this.

```
./program -i /path -o /path -nomore
```

The `-nomore` argument is optional. If you type it, it hides some output infos, if you don't, it doesn't (so default is not to hide the output infos).
I ve made a python script to run this program.
So: `myscript.py -i /path/ -o/path -nomore`
That's what i want to achieve.

```
import argparse, subprocess
parser.add_argument("-i","--query", type=str, required=True)
parser.add_argument("-d","--database", type=str, required=True)
parser.add_argument('-nomore','--nomore')
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.nomore:
    print 'nomore activated'
subprocess.call("program -i %s -o %s %s "  % (args.query, args.database, args.nomore,),shell=True )
```

Thing is whether i put `-nomore` option or not, the only thing that changes is that 'nomore activated' is printed, without any functional change.

I also tried

```
parser.add_argument('-nomore','--nomore',action=store_true)
```

but I got: `Uknown option true ignored` , when i put in the command line `-nocons`, and `unknown option false ignored` when i didnt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I got this. Solved it by using action="store_const" in the arguments and setting default=True.

```
import argparse, subprocess
parser.add_argument("-i","--query", type=str, required=True)
parser.add_argument("-d","--database", type=str, required=True)
parser.add_argument('-nomore','--nomore', action='store_const', default=True)
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.nomore:
    print 'nomore activated'
subprocess.call("program -i %s -o %s %s "  % (args.query, args.database, args.nomore,),shell=True
```

That solved my problem. Still not fully understanding why action='store_true' is so different from action='store_const' in this case though.

Comment: Is the problem that you have both '-nomore' and '--nomore' for the same argument? I haven't tried it but typically you would have '-n' and '--nomore' or just '--nomore', that is you don't have to have two versions of the argument with argparse.  Maybe that's what confuses it, as you say 'store_true' should work for what you want.